# SQL Server DDL script to append (or drop) the same set of columns for every table in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ddl

How would one write a sql server DDL script that can:

For each table in database:

```
add column CreatedBy
add column CreateDate
add column UpdatedBy
add column UpdatedDate
```

Also, if the particular column already exists on the table, just skip that column.

Also, the reverse of it, for each table, drop those 4 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)

DECLARE curTables CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

OPEN curTables

FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME='CreatedBy')
            EXECUTE ('ALTER TABLE [' + @TableName + '] ADD CreatedBy VARCHAR(50)')

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME='CreatedDate')
            EXECUTE ('ALTER TABLE [' + @TableName + '] ADD CreatedDate DATETIME')

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME='UpdatedBy')
            EXECUTE ('ALTER TABLE [' + @TableName + '] ADD UpdatedBy VARCHAR(50)')

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME='UpdatedDate')
            EXECUTE ('ALTER TABLE [' + @TableName + '] ADD UpdatedDate DATETIME')


        FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableName   
    END

CLOSE curTables
DEALLOCATE curTables
```

Then the opposite is just a case of changing `IF NOT EXISTS` to `IF EXISTS` and the ALTER statements to `ALTER TABLE...DROP [ColumnName]`

Answer (score 0):

Great sample, AdaTheDev!
However, I made a small change to it to ignore tables in various schemas, views and aspnet membership tables. You can easily chan ge it if you want to just process tables in a certain schemas.

Here's my version:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @TableSchema NVARCHAR(128)

DECLARE curTables CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' and (TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('schems1', 'schems2') and  TABLE_NAME not like 'aspnet_%')
OPEN curTables

FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableSchema, @TableName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME='Locked')
            EXECUTE ('ALTER TABLE  [' + @TableSchema + '].[' + @TableName + '] ADD Locked bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_' + @TableSchema + '_' + @TableName + '_Locked DEFAULT 0')

        FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableSchema, @TableName
    END

CLOSE curTables
DEALLOCATE curTables
```